# The result of the query does not make sense

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying a database but the result it gives me is pointless. According to the BD there are 5 different books of which there are a total of 7 copies, from book 1,3 and 5 -> 1 copy of book 2 and 4 there are 2 of each. On loan we have that book 1 and 4 have been Borrowed 2 times, Book 2 has been borrowed 3 times, and Book 5 and 3 have been borrowed 1 time. The query statement is this

From this database, it is intended to create a report with iReport that reflects the loans made for each issue, including its edition, for each title. In addition, for each title the total loans of the copies that exist for said title will be obtained

My query is

```
Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l,
     Ejemplares e,
     Prestamos p
where l.id = e.idLibro = p.idLibro
```

nevertheless the result that throws does not make sense, it is:

```
   titulo                          edicion  count(p.idLibro)
Los pilares de la tierra             2010             14
```

It doesn't make sense if we match the id should all the books come out, not just 1 plus where does 14 count? if book 1 has only been checked out 2 times
this is the link of BD

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lj0AZFDS4UajTLebL4IwBFw5GspOZl1q
```

Comment: That query is invalid and should raise an exception.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You also need a `GROUP BY` clause here.

Comment: Yes if necesary group by thanks

Comment: Other question i need insert 1 parameter, if ID is = or > thah one number thah i said. IF i whrite Select l.titulo, e.edicion, count(p.idLibro)
from Libros l, Ejemplares e, Prestamos p
where l.id = e.idLibro = p.idLibro,l.id>1
GROUP by l.id;

gives an error says: # 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near 'e.idBook> = 1
GROUP by l.id LIMIT 0, 25 'on line 3

Comment: If `where l.id = e.idLibro = p.idLibro` doesn't raise an exception probably it behaves as follows.`l.id = e.idLibro` returns a boolean and then the boolean is compared to `p.idLibro` with an implicit cast of that. So not at all what you were probably hoping. You probably wanted `where l.id = e.idLibro and e.idLibro = p.idLibro` though you should just use explicit `join` keyword